# Search results: only display matrix rows that contain the search item

Tags: matrix, search

I've found out how to search and display matrix rows, but the search results page will typically only show ALL rows.

How can I limit the results and show only the row where the item exists?

> {exp:search:search_results}
>   {title}
>   {matrix_stuff}{matrix_title}{/matrix_stuff}
>   {/exp:search:search_results}

EDIT:
There is a hack that works, but not a definite answer:

In mod.search.php add after line 1298( before $pagination):

```
// hack
// Load the XML Helper
$this->EE->load->helper('xml');

$keywords = $this->EE->functions->encode_ee_tags(xml_convert($query->row('keywords')));
// end hack
```

And after line 1411 before $channel->fetch_categories();

```
// hack add keywords
$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = str_replace(LD.'keywords'.RD, $keywords, $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
// end hack
```

This makes it possible to use this:

```
{exp:search:search_results}
{title}
{matrix_stuff search:matrix_col_name="{keywords}"}}{matrix_title}{/matrix_stuff}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Not implemented in 2.7.0 :-(

Answer (score 2):

Make the sure the matrix field and columns are searchable first. Then you could do something like what I have below, but you're limited to what matrix columns you can search.

```
{exp:search:search_results}
    {my_matrix_field search:matrix_col="{exp:search:keywords}"}
        {matrix_title}
    {/my_matrix_field}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Like Robson mentioned below, you can do either a "contains" matching (above) or an "exact" matching search by adding the `=` in front of the `{exp:search:keywords}`

Comment: I can't edit your answer. You need to remove one "=". We need a “Contains” Matching, not a “Exact” Matching: 'search:matrix_col="{exp:search:key...'

Comment: Siebird, thanks very much, this seemed like the perfect answer, however, when used inside the {exp:search:search_results} tag, the {exp:search:keywords} is annoyingly outputted as the string that is used in the URL.

Comment: That's odd. What happens when you use the `{exp:search:search_results}` tag outside of the matrix  ?

Comment: The same, 
{exp:search:search_results}
    {exp:search:keywords}
{/exp:search:search_results}
results in a string too

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: Expression Engine 2.5.5

Comment: I'm at a lost with this one, might be a bug. I just checked one of my EE sites running 2.6.1 with simple search and `exp:search:keyword` tag parse correctly with the search terms.

Comment: I was testing on a site running EECMS 2.6.1 while @Siebird wrote his answer and worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, that's nasty, I'm reluctant to upgrade because of compatibility issues. I'll try to figure out if it's a version bug and let you know. Might upgrade, but that could take some tine.

Comment: I just thought of this last night, does your search form have the correct input names? ie. `<input type="text" name="keywords">`

Comment: Well Siebird it seems like this is a parse order issue. Outside matrix this only happens when using {exp:search:keyword} outside and inside the results tag pair. Removing the first makes it work However still not inside Matrix. Now it shows every row with "} at the end of the line.

Comment: Hi were you able to fix this? i seem to be having the same problem too endings with "} "} "}

Comment: No I haven't I'm afraid :-(

Comment: There was a hack from Ellislab that made it work for me using the {keyword} variable. They did not implement it in newer versions, so I guess that upgrading EE will get the issue back

Comment: See the answer in my edited question, not a final answer but workable

Comment: Are you using `{exp:search:keywords}` twice and having issues? Please, try `{exp:search:keywords random}`

Answer (score 1):

Ok found a simpler way to get this to work
with an embed (have not tested with native EE search)

Source:

- https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/limiting_search_results_by_matrix_column_data
- http://pastie.org/4228399

Comment: Sounds good, but you'll need to get Low Search for this in order to make it work. Still, this is a better solution then hacking around in EE

Answer (score 0):

Install Mo' Variables: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables

Change your template to this:

```
{exp:search:search_results}
    {my_matrix_field search:matrix_col="{post:keywords}"}
        {matrix_title}
    {/my_matrix_field}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Comment: Thank Brian. I've tested it, but that didn't work I'm afraid. It displays all rows with "} at the end. So again a familiar parse order issue. Not sure if that's the case for everyone, because Ellislab made a hack in mod.search.php (xml conversion)

Comment: I've tested it without the hack from Elislab, but the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Sift?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sift

It should do what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, i wasn't aware of that, I'll take a look!

Comment: Sift is specific for matrix search/filtering only.